# MYSQL toggle enum values on each call

Tags: mysql, sql

I want this to be like this.

I have an `ENUM` column with 0 AND 1, i want to toggle between these two values on each query.

```
UPDATE settings
SET state = 1 IF state = 0 
              ELSE IF state = 0 
                   SET STATE = 1 WHERE id = '$id';
```

I tried this, but it leaves the column empty.

```
UPDATE settings SET state = IF(state=1, 0, 1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not SET state = (1 - state) WHERE... If the column is initially NULL, you have to set default value = 0 or use state= 1- IFNULL(state,0)

Comment: Its not initially NULL, its initially '0'.

Comment: Ok, then "state = 1 - state" will work. When 1 it will be set to 0, and when 0 - to 1.

Comment: @i486 maybe there's something wrong with my system, this acts like the answer below. Sets state = '', and them '0', then ''; not 1. Anyway, can you put this as the answer and explain the maths?

Comment: Define column as INT or TINYINT (or even BIT). With enum it looks like string/varchar, i.e. no math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like `enum` for [various reasons](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/). Especially when you use it to store `0` and `1` it can be confusing, yes, even error prone.

Use a tinyint, it's much easier to use and more readable.

```
mysql> create table switch(state tinyint default 0);

mysql> insert into switch values (0);

mysql> select * from switch;
+-------+
| state |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+

mysql> update switch set state = not state; /*simple as that :)*/

mysql> select * from switch;
+-------+
| state |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+

mysql> update switch set state = not state;

mysql> select * from switch;
+-------+
| state |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

Comment: 1 and 0 are treated as true and false.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple if statement :

```
mysql > UPDATE switch SET state=if(state=0,1,0);
```